# Multi-Threading transmission in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, netty

I use Python Client to connect with  Netty server.

Client :

```
import socket 
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import threading
import sys
import time

starttimes = sys.argv[1]
starttimes = int(starttimes)
endtimes = sys.argv[2]
endtimes = int(endtimes)
times = endtimes - starttimes

open('result.csv','w').close()
csv_file = 'result.csv'

def loop():
    TCP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
    TCP_PORT = 9999                   # The same port as used by the server
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    timereq = datetime.now()
    timereq2 = datetime.strftime(timereq, '%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S.%f')
    timereq3 = time.time()
    s.sendall("\x00\x00"+i)
    res = s.recv(4096)
    print res
    timeres = datetime.now()
    timeres2 = datetime.strftime(timeres, '%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S.%f')
    timeres3 = time.time()
    s.close()
    print('Received', repr(res))
    cost = timeres3 - timereq3
    cost = "%.3f" % cost
    with open(csv_file, 'a') as csvfile:

        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow([timereq2, timeres2, cost])


threads = []
for i in range(starttimes,endtimes+1):
    i =chr(i)
    t = threading.Thread(target=loop)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

For example , I set variable "i" in multi-thread between 1 to 10 , the ideal result in server is getting "i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10".

But sometimes it would get something wrong, such as "i = 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10" or  "i = 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 8, 9, 9".

Please kindly help me to solve the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the local variable `i` which has changed in the meanwhile.
Pass it like this:

```
threading.Thread(target=loop, args=(i,))
```

And add it as an argument to the `loop` function:

```
def loop(i):
    ...
```